# How to count how many times each element occurs in an array?

Tags: python, arrays

lets say we have this array:

```
Sample_array = [1,2,4,4,5,1,2,4]
```

and we want to know how many times each element occurs in this array, without using numpy what is the easiest and simplest way to do it?

Comment: `list.count(element)` use this

Comment: so it would be like this?

for x in Sample_array:
Sample_array.count(x)

??

Comment: yes, you may also use `dit = {x:lst.count(x) for x in lst}` this will give the count of each element in the form of dictionary

Comment: ahh okay, gotcha. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an internal python library named Counter like below:

```
from collections import Counter                                                                                                                        

Counter(Sample_array)                                                                                                                                  
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 4: 3, 5: 1})
```